# Strange behavior in Studio3T/Mongo

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

As the Title suggests, I found a rather strange behavior which I am not sure to attribute to Studio3T or to MongoDB.

I have a collection containing simple documents, as follows:

[Example of a document in the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qq8h.png)

Whenever I perform a query using the query builder, everything works as expected. However, when I do it using IntelliShell or Aggregate **AND** if such query is based on the field StudyID, no document is returned, regardless the query.

For example, the two following queries return, respectively, an empty list and no documents.

```
db.Cortisol.distinct("StudyID")
db.Cortisol.find({},{"StudyID" : 1})
```

While the following very similar query returns the documents, as expected.

```
db.Cortisol.find({},{"ExamID" : 1})
```

As you can see the queries are correct, I did not misspell anything so does anyone have a possible explanation for such a strange behavior?

Comment: Does it work in native mongo shell? As a side note, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to increase your chances to get an answer.

Comment: No, the result is the same.

Comment: So wouldn't it be fair to assume the problem is not with Studio3T? Please provide some examples to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your field "StudyID" contains some weird (invisible) unicode chars. This would explain why dragging the field into query builder works (because the query builder uses the exact same string) and typing S-t-u-d-y-I-D doesn't.
When you run an empty query and you see documents with StudyID returned, can you then copy the field name of your StudyID field to the clipboard, and then when you type your query in IntelliShell paste the StudyID name?

Comment: This identified the problem!

As advised, I copied the problematic's field name to the clipboard and paste it in the query. The query works, as opposed to when I write it char by char.

This supports the hypothesis that there is some invisible char. This is further proven by: when I move the caret with the keyboard through the field's name, I have to press the arrow two times to "go through" the S character, which indicates that this invisible char is before the 'S' in the field "StudyID".